# Как получить простые числа

Tags: python

Вроде простая задача и все в коде понятно кроме самой логики определения простого числа.
Код из книги:

```
def main():
    
    # Локальная переменная
    number = 0

    # Получить число
    number = int(input('Введите целое число: '))

    # Показать информацию о том, является ли число простым
    if is_prime(number):
        print('Введенное вами число является простым.')
    else:
        print('Введенное вами число не является простым.')

# Функция is_prime получает в качестве аргумента число и
# возвращает True, если число простое, и False в противном случае. 
def is_prime(number):
    # Локальные переменные
    half = int(number / 2)
    status = True

    for count in range(2, half + 1):
        if number % count == 0:
            status = False
        
    return status

# Вызвать главную функцию.
main()
```

Почему переменной half присваивается целое значение половины введенного числа и потом half+1 используется как конец цикла?

Comment: Простое число - это число которое делится на 1 и на самого себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы проверить что число простое в данном алгоритме он делится на все числа от `2` до `int(number / 2)` включительно (поэтому и `half + 1`)

очевидно, что если число не делится на какое-то число в диапазоне `0 ..number / 2`, то оно не делится на любое числа в диапазоне `number / 2 .. number` и поэтому проверять на делимость дальше не нужно

ведь если число `a` делится на число `b` из диапазона `number / 2 .. number`:

```
c = a / b
```

то оно делится и на число `c` из диапазона `0 ..number / 2`

**Но это неоптимальный алгоритм**, потому что достаточно проверить все числа в диапазоне `2 .. sqrt(number)` и если число не делится ни на одно число из этого диапазона, то оно простое.

На этом принципе основано решето Эратосфена поиска простых чисел - когда вы рассматриваете только `sqrt(n)` чисел чтобы найти все простые числа до `n`

**P.S.**

по хорошему надо проверить делимость на 2, а дальше в диапазоне проверять только нечётные числа

а еще как только найден делитель - не надо проверять остальные числа и так понятно, что число составное и можно выходить

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    # Локальные переменные
    sqrt_num = int(number**.5)

    for count in range(3, sqrt_num + 1, 2):
        if number % count == 0:
            return False
        
    return True
```